# Android - Java: расстояние между нулями

Tags: android, java

Есть строка с числом. Число может быть большое. Например 1000000 или 10000.

Нужно, чтобы числа выглядели так: 1 000 000 и 10 000 (можно с нулями).

я пытался сделать это нечто таким:

```
String.replace("000"," 000");
```

Но выходило как-то не очень.

Спасибо.

Comment: Да, вот так и рождаются чудовища-кадавры - а ведь чего проще достаточно почитать документацию или просто [погуглить](https://www.google.ru/#q=java%20number%20format%20group%20separator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static String format(int value) {
    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat();
    DecimalFormatSymbols fmts = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    fmts.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
    fmt.setGroupingSize(3);
    fmt.setGroupingUsed(true);
    fmt.setDecimalFormatSymbols(fmts);
    return fmt.format(value);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

[DecimalFormatSymbols](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html) был придуман именно для этого. `getGroupingSeparator()` используется для установки символа разделяющего тысячи.